# CordovaActivity loading external url performance

Tags: android, performance, cordova

I have created a phonegap application with the default phonegap commands:

$ cordova create hello com.example.hello "HelloWorld"

$ cd hello

$ cordova platform add android

$ cordova build

Next I have added the project to Eclipse and in the activity changed the url to load an external website. Now when I start the application on the simulator it took like 7 seconds to load a simple remote website (in this case google.com) On a real device it's taking a shorter time, but also too long, like 3-4 seconds.

If I use the default page, which is a local website (Index.html) it's fast enough.

Any ideas why an external page is taking so much more time to load?

Below is the code in my CordovaActivity:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        super.loadUrl("http://www.google.nl");
        //super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
```

Comment: Don't you think few seconds are required to load the files from Google server over internet!!